# Instantiating L to a list of digits Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

If I have the following database:

```
digit(0).
digit(1).
digit(2).
digit(3).
digit(4).
digit(5).
digit(6).
digit(7).
digit(8).
digit(9).
```

I want the query

```
digits([X,Y]).
```

to succeed by instantiating X and Y to 10*10 = 100 different combinations of digits, how would I go about this?

Would I need to use finite domain constraints for this and something like

```
L ins 0..9
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need clpfd to do that. You can use higher order to obtain an expressive solution:

```
digits(L) :- maplist(digit, L).
```

You can also do the recursion yourself:

```
digits([]) :- [].
digits([H|T]) :- digit(H), digits(T).
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) is straight-forward:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- length(Zs, 3), Zs ins 1..2, labeling([], Zs).
  Zs = [1,1,1]
; Zs = [1,1,2]
; Zs = [1,2,1]
; Zs = [1,2,2]
; Zs = [2,1,1]
; Zs = [2,1,2]
; Zs = [2,2,1]
; Zs = [2,2,2].
```